# Not able to view line breaks i.e. \n

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have lightning component, which shows a dynamic message -4

Here is the component  code--

```
                        <!-- Success Message Start -->
                    <div class="slds-region_narrow slds-is-relative slds-m-top_small">
                        <div class="slds-theme_success slds-notify slds-notify_toast">
                            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-m-right_small slds-no-flex slds-align-top">
                                <lightning:icon class="slds-icon_small" iconName="utility:success" alternativeText="Success!" size="small" variant="inverse"></lightning:icon>
                            </span>
                            <div class="slds-notify__content">
                                <!-- Keeping preformatted considering different formatting sent from different componennts-->
                                <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small"><p>{!v.successMessage}</p></h2>
                            </div>
                            <!--div class="slds-notify__close">
                                <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-m-left_small" alternativeText="Close" iconClass="" variant="bare-inverse" type="button" iconName="utility:close" size="large" onclick="{! c.close}"></lightning:buttonIcon>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>              
                    </div>
                <!-- Success Message End -->
```

Problem is when I try to set v.succesMessage with  a text like ABCD \n DEF , it  is not taking the line breaks, it shows properly in console logs and alerts.

I tried to use `<p>` instead of `<h2>` but it didn't work.

What can be the problem? which the class getting wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can you try <br/> isntead for line breaks?

Comment: no..the problem is that attribute is set from other components,basically when something completes I fire an event with the corresponding message, and it catches in this component. One of the component, I have requirement to show multiple lines,so I am setting \n in the event string attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use aura:unescapedHtml and format your message to use HTML tags rather than newline characters. Something along the following lines:

```
<!-- Success Message Start -->
    <div class="slds-region_narrow slds-is-relative slds-m-top_small">
        <div class="slds-theme_success slds-notify slds-notify_toast">
            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-m-right_small slds-no-flex slds-align-top">
                <lightning:icon class="slds-icon_small" iconName="utility:success" alternativeText="Success!" size="small" variant="inverse"></lightning:icon>
            </span>
            <div class="slds-notify__content">
                <!-- Keeping preformatted considering different formatting sent from different componennts-->
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small"><p><aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.successMessage}"/></p></h2>
            </div>
            <!--div class="slds-notify__close">
                <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-m-left_small" alternativeText="Close" iconClass="" variant="bare-inverse" type="button" iconName="utility:close" size="large" onclick="{! c.close}"></lightning:buttonIcon>
            </div> -->
        </div>              
    </div>
<!-- Success Message End -->
```

And successMessage should contain a string that looks like:

```
'This is a test<p>with a paragraph break.'
```

rather than

```
'This is a test\n with a newline.'
```

Comment: will it work for normal strings as well?

Comment: If by *normal* strings you mean strings that don't have any HTML or special characters in them, yes.

Comment: Worked.. thanks

Comment: Even i am facing the problem I have used aura:unescapedHtml but the format is not looking good.
I am getting the text from html email template (which has break tags) and displaying in lightning component. [![Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBUfI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBUfI.png)

Comment: @m.dinesh Do you mean it has `\n` or '<br/>`?